# Can I edit visually selected text in a different buffer?

Tags: visual-mode

I often use `vim` via terminal wrapper (e.g. `gnome-terminal --disable-factory --command='vim /tmp/firefox12345.txt'`) to edit a textarea on websites, e.g. when writing this question.

Whenever I put in a block of code I wonder if I can somehow:

1. visually select whole indented part of text in the current buffer
2. open it in a new one
3. change the filetype to match the syntax (e.g. javascript)
4. edit, write and close it
5. have vim "update" all my changes in the original buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try the Emacs-inspired [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) ("narrow region") plugin.

Should allow you to do exactly what you ask - but you'll probably have to `set filetype=javascript` (as an example) yourself (or perhaps run `filetype detect`) in the narrowed region.

Comment: vim-sleuth may be a good plugin to have in order to automatically pick up indentation settings. (https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth)

Comment: If NrrwRgn doesn't bring the filetype of the original buffer with it, perhaps it could be modified to do so... Although if it is often used to handle snippets of embedded code (of a different filetype) then perhaps an automatic `filetype detect` would be preferable.

Comment: One could probably use `:h NR-hooks` for this :)